# File IMG from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

Is it possible to convert or open an IMG file from OSM?
I don't find a solution for the visualization and conversion.

Comment: Are you looking for OSM to Garmin IMG conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Map_On_Garmin) lists several tools that can convert from OSM to Garmin IMG and general conversion and installation instructions.